# is there an React equivalent to Angular(1)'s angular.element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When debugging or adding Feature tests, it is sometimes much easier to highlight the element in ELEMENT view and then use the console to grab the component by the html ELEMENT.

Angular provided this with `angular.element($0)`

I notice react sprinkles `react-id="10.0.0.8.1.0.$=10.0.1"` everywhere, now question is can i use the magic here to find the component in console?

with/without using react developer extension.

---

EDIT: as an example, I am writing E2E tests that need to trigger `onmouseenter` for a react component, which doesn't seem to work with my version of React and Capybara-webkit (hover and mouseenter doesnt seem to trigger the handler), nor does running any javascript to select the element and trigger the native event ( from my understanding, React.Event#`onmouseenter` is a synthesized event ). I would rather just trigger it somehow, even with a `React.getComponent($0).handleMouseEnter(new Event(....))`.

Comment: I think you need to specify your use case better. Is this only for testing/debugging? Why do you need to access the React component? Give us an example here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) for Chrome or [React Developer Tools for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/react-devtools/).

It's really helpful when developing React Components.

Comment: how about without, like im wondering what its donig underneath the hood that allows us to find the original component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ReactDOM's findDOMNode](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) method to get the underlying DOM node for your React component.

For debugging it's a good choice, but generally you should follow the advice in the React documentation:

> In most cases, you can attach a ref to the DOM node and avoid using findDOMNode at all.